# How to change image css after rotating it in JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

There is nice css trick to always position image in the center of div regardless of image size or aspect ratio.

```
<style>
.img_wrap {
    padding-bottom: 56.25%;
    width: 100%; 
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#imgpreview {
    display: block;
    max-height: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
}
</style>
<div class="img_wrap">
  <img id="imgpreview" src="http://i.imgur.com/RRUe0Mo.png" alt="your image" />
</div>
```

Then I added jquery code for rotating image

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var rotation = 0;

    jQuery.fn.rotate = function(degrees) {
        $(this).css({'-webkit-transform' : 'rotate('+ degrees +'deg)',
                     '-moz-transform' : 'rotate('+ degrees +'deg)',
                     '-ms-transform' : 'rotate('+ degrees +'deg)',
                     'transform' : 'rotate('+ degrees +'deg)'});
    };

    $('#imgpreview').click(function() {
        rotation += 90;
        $(this).rotate(rotation);
        // $(this).toggleClass("imgpreview");
    });
});
```

However, when I am rotation image, it gets cropped. I want to avoid that.

I tried to play with addClass feature but with no success. If someone could suggest any solution would appreciate a lot.

I have created [jsfidlle](https://jsfiddle.net/nm7g3sug/) for this question. 
Here the [updated](https://jsfiddle.net/nm7g3sug/4/) fiddle

Comment: remove `overflow: hidden;` from the .img-wrap and it will not crop

Comment: Sorry, I have not properly explained the question. What I meant is that I want the rotated image to take img_wrap size. In this case the original picture is landscape oriented so on rotating for 90 degrees I want it to "shrink" in width so that the width would take the value of img_wrap height.

Comment: note that `img_wrap` has zero height - any height it has is from the `padding-bottom`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this is what I did to your code:

1. Removed the `overflow: hidden` for `img_wrap`.
2. In JS I did this:

   ```
     $('.imgpreview').click(function() {
       rotation += 90;
       rotation %= 360;
       $(this).rotate(rotation);

       // when rotation is 90 or 270
       if ((rotation / 90) & 1) {
         $(this).css({
           'width': $('.img_wrap').innerHeight(),
           'max-height': $('.img_wrap').innerWidth()
         });
       } else {
         $(this).css({
           'width': 'auto',
           'max-height': '100%'
         });
       }
     });
   ```
3. Note that the `width`/`height` calculations are done after the call to `rotate` function. **After rotation, `width` is `height` and vice-versa for the `imgpreview` and so we have to allow `height` to adjust while setting `width` of `imgpreview` - hence the `max-height` style adjustment.**

See demo below:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var rotation = 0;

  jQuery.fn.rotate = function(degrees) {
    $(this).css({
      '-webkit-transform': 'rotate(' + degrees + 'deg)',
      '-moz-transform': 'rotate(' + degrees + 'deg)',
      '-ms-transform': 'rotate(' + degrees + 'deg)',
      'transform': 'rotate(' + degrees + 'deg)'
    });
  };

  $('.imgpreview').click(function() {
    rotation += 90;
    rotation %= 360;
    $(this).rotate(rotation);

    // when rotation is 90 or 270
    if ((rotation / 90) & 1) {
      $(this).css({
        'width': $('.img_wrap').innerHeight(),
        'max-height': $('.img_wrap').innerWidth()
      });
    } else {
      $(this).css({
        'width': 'auto',
        'max-height': '100%'
      });
    }
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.img_wrap {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  border: 3px solid black;
  padding-bottom: 56.25%;
  /*overflow: hidden;*/
}
.imgpreview {
  display: block;
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="img_wrap" id="P">
  <img class="imgpreview" id="Pim" src="https://3.bp.blogspot.com/-W__wiaHUjwI/Vt3Grd8df0I/AAAAAAAAA78/7xqUNj8ujtY/s1600/image02.png" alt="your image" />
</div>
<br/>
<div class="img_wrap">
  <img class="imgpreview" src="http://i.imgur.com/RRUe0Mo.png" alt="your image" />
</div>
```

Comment: While this is a great implementation it does not work for me. The wrapper is inside BS modal. If using vh then image goes outside the modal. I have updated the fidlle with my solution - the trick is to use `innerHeigt()` instead of `heigt()`. Could I ask you what is the purpose of this line `rotation %= 360;` in your code?

Comment: of course, I set `100vh` just for illustration... `rotation%=360` ensures that the variable `rotation` will always range from `0` upto `360`

Comment: you can replace `100vh` in `img_wrap` css and in the JS code to the value of the height of the container, does that sound good?

Comment: Yes it seems to be ok, but I have another problem now. Here is updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nm7g3sug/6/). Problem is that this trick does not work for portrait oriented images.

Comment: I didn't get your issue - you are using jquery `toggle` on clicking the *toggle landscape* button? I'm confused....

Comment: oh, sorry, the toggle button is left from my development state. 
The problem is that when I rotate the portrait(dog) image height does not changes together with width.

Comment: you are calling `$(this).rotate(rotation)` after the `width` / `height` calculations... will update the answer with a solution now...

Comment: @KārlisJanisels see the updated answer and let me know your thoughts...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128858/discussion-between-krlis-janisels-and-kukkuz).

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this with jquery by altering a little bit your code:

```
$('#imgpreview').click(function() {
    if (rotation === 360) {
        rotation = 0
    } else {
        rotation += 90;
    }
    $(this).rotate(rotation);
    if(rotation === 90 || rotation === 270) {
        $('.img_wrap').css('height', $(this).width());
    } else {
        $('.img_wrap').css('height', 'auto');
    }
});
```

There's maybe the need to alter your css also but it depends what is the end result that you wish to have.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it was realy useful. I have upadated the fiddle with end result!

Comment: Glad I helped :) Some acceptance and upvoting would be awesome ;)

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do that.
The jQuery below is determine whether it is vertical or not.
You just need to add this line into your function(degrees)

```
((degrees/90) == 1 || (degrees/90) == 3)? $(this).css('width','56.25%'):$(this).css('width','auto');
```

[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1x80vj0j/2/)